# Como obter o valor de uma tabela dependendo do valor maximo de outra?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho o seguinte código que me dá uma tabela como a da imagem, mas a minha duvida é como é que eu faço para só obter o nome e apenas o nome do que tem o maior valor de saude que será a gasolina? É possivel usar um NOT EXISTS neste caso?

```
SELECT O.nome, SUM(E.saude)
FROM Objecto O, Elemento E, composto C
WHERE O.marca = C.prodMarca AND C.produto = O.codigo AND C.elemento = E.codigo
GROUP BY O.nome
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas o NOT EXISTS seria usado com qual outra query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT O.nome, SUM(E.saude) as valorSaude 
FROM Objecto O, Elemento E, composto C
WHERE O.marca = C.prodMarca AND C.produto = O.codigo AND C.elemento = E.codigo
GROUP BY O.nome order by valorSaude desc limit 1
```

Assim ele ordena pelo valorSaude de forma descendente `order by valorSaude desc` e pega apenas o primeiro resultado `limit 1`

Comment: E onde está `valorSaude` no seu select?

Comment: Tomando como base a imagem que ele passou acredito que o `valorSaude` seja o `SUM(E.saude)` alterei minha resposta

Comment: Só preciso mesmo de obter o nome e nao o valor. Há outra opção usando o NOT EXISTS? (esqueci-me de referir na pergunta , vou já alterar)

Comment: @ForçaChape não entendi onde você gostaria de utilizar o `NOT EXISTS` nesse caso? Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Não sei se é possivel mas criando um sub-interrogação no WHERE com um NOT EXISTS ?

Comment: @ForçaChape como você obtém o `valorSaude`?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando um `sub select` ficaria dessa forma, ao meu ver:

```
SELECT O.nome, SUM(E.saude) as somaSaude
FROM Objecto O, Elemento E, composto C
WHERE O.marca = C.prodMarca AND C.produto = O.codigo AND C.elemento = E.codigo
AND somaSaude = (
    SELECT MAX(SUM(E.saude))
    FROM Objecto O, Elemento E, composto C
    WHERE O.marca = C.prodMarca AND C.produto = O.codigo AND C.elemento = E.codigo
)
```

Comment: Sim , mas agora que percebi que nao faz sentido usar um sub select para o caso que estou a fazer